# Making equations into common bases

Tags: logarithms

How would you make the equation $64\left(\frac 47\right)^{2x}=343$ so that it has a common base? I understand how to solve it using logs but could anyone show me how to solves it by making the numbers into common bases, thanks.

Comment: Hint: can you factor 343 and 64?

Comment: Yes, i can factor 343 into 7^3 and 64 into either 2^6, 4^3 or 8^2, but it still wouldn't leave me with a common base, right?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $64=4^3,343=7^3$

$$\dfrac{343}{64}=\left(\dfrac74\right)^3=\left(\dfrac47\right)^{-3}$$

Now $x^a=x^b\implies$

either $x=1$

or $x=0; a,b>0$

or $x=-1,a-b$ is even

or $a=b$

Comment: I understand now, thank you!